# How to schedule this multiple thread application?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, operating-system

lets have example..

some complex work is divided by 4 thread

```
thread -A is calling function_A
thread -B is calling function_B
thread -C is calling function_C
thread -D is calling function_D
```

now condition is that thread A,B,C can work at same time but when ever thread D is executing function_D it will see does any thread from A,B,C is executing there function ? if yes then it will wait for them completion and when no thread from a,b,c is executing there function, thread D will start to execute function D.

How can i do that ? any ruff idea?

**EDIT : function_A,function_B,function_c is using one handle. and function_D is closing that handle. When ever any function is using that handle it should not be closed by function_d.**

Comment: If you want to learn a little bit more on using semaphores (besides using the answers below), you might want to read "The Little Book of Semaphores" http://greenteapress.com/semaphores/ .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like a job for a counting semaphore.

Each thread using the handle should increment the semaphore value. Thread D should wait on the semaphore to reach zero.

If you implement this without care for when thread D runs, do not be surprised if thread D runs before A, B or C and closes the handle immediately.

Comment: how can i make thread d to wait on the semaphre 0 ? i know sem_wait() but cannot use it in this way

Comment: @Mr.32: You will probably need to use `semop` and friends. They are more complicated than `sem_wait` and have more options.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to synchronize these threads yourself, The OS will not gaurantee any synchronization.
Simplest way is by using **[Semaphores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29)** or Conditional Variables.

Comment: @Mr.32: Have a look at the Wikipedia Link.It explains the concept in simple words with a example.In short Semaphore is nothing but a shared counter which you can use accross threads for synchronizing them.

Answer (score 3):

You should look at information about synchronization control.

Depends on your design, there can be lots of way to achieve such behavior:

1. Thread A-C acquires its own mutex/critical section before running, and Thread D acquires all their mutexes before it run.
2. Have a counting semaphore with count of 3.  Thread A-C acquires the semaphore once while Thread D acquires that semaphore 3 times
3. Making use of a reader-writer lock, Thread A-C acquires reader lock, while Thread D acquires writer lock

etc....

All it depends on your design and you are the only one here who knows which strategy is most rational in your design.

Comment: superb answer..i am going with semaphore